# Database results displaying in reverse order of inline and block from what is assigned

Tags: php, html, css, while-loop

I'm attempting to output info from my db through a while loop. I am wanting the results to display like this...

Firstname  Lastname - Firstname Lastname - Firstname Lastname

player1     ---------------player1-----------------------player1

player2 ----------------player2-------------------------player2

player3   ------------------player3----------------------player3

However my results are displaying like this...

Firstname Lastname

player1 - player2 - player3

Firstname Lastname

player1 - player2 - player3

etc

firstname, lastname, player1, player2, and player 3 are all columns in my db table. Every time there is a new user, they get inserted into a new row with new players.

Code:

```
<h1>Draft Order</h1>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_players");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    $player1 = $row['player1'];
    $player2 = $row['player2'];
    $player3 = $row['player3'];
?>
        <div class="inline">
        <?php echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="draftBorder">
<?php
echo $player1;
echo $player2;
echo $player3;
?>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

CSS

```
.inline {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
/*------Draft Page---*/
.draftBorder {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
```

I have the firstname and lastname fields in a class called 'inline' to make those fields inline, but they are showing up as block.

I have the players in a class called 'draftBorder' and set that to block, but it is showing up inline.

Why are these showing up reversed and how can I change it to get my desired result.

UPDATE: Now showing like...

firstname - lastname

player1

player2

player3

firstname lastname

player1

player2

player3

firstname lastname

player1

player2

player3

UPDATE: from the `float: left;` suggestion

firstname lastname ------player1

player3------------------player2

firstname lastname ------player1

player3------------------player2

firstname lastname ------player1

player3------------------player2

Comment: I don't know what you are expecting, but it looks like you are just inserting text into 2 divs. Defining `display:block;` on the parent div doesn't make your `$player` variables display block... it's just text in a div

Comment: How can I make the $player variables display block and the firstname & lastname variables display inline?

Comment: Try wrapping them in `<div>`'s like this: `<div><?php echo $player1;<?php></div>` maybe. I don't know php though

Comment: Ok that worked for the `$players`. I tried to wrap the firstname and lastname echo line in a div like the $players, but that did nothing. I will update my question to show how it is displaying.

Comment: Try setting your `.inline` css class to `display:inline-block;` if that doesn't work you could try adding `float:left;`

Comment: `inline-block` did nothing. float left brought the other names up, but they are displaying as block. I will update my question to show results.

Comment: Ok try removing the `float` you just applied to `.inline`. Then wrap both `.inline` and `.draftBorder` in a div (a container for each set of these divs in the loop) and give that div a `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;`. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand CSS, just can't figure out how to make this work. I wrapped those two divs and tried the float and inline-block and both did the same. It displayed everything as a block basically. The same as my first update

Comment: Are your variables coming in the order you want them to? It may be your CSS is fine but your while loop is producing the results in a way you would not expect. Are your echo of `$player1,2,3` as expected? have you tried  += in your while loop ?

Comment: @zgood Sorry, your last suggestion worked. My php file didn't upload. I had in in my queued file part of my ftp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I completely understand the requirement here but please give this code a show and let me know the result.

```
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    $stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", first_name, last_name) AS fullname, player1, player2, player3 FROM user_players");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {

    echo '<h1>Draft Order</h1>';

    echo '<div style="display: block; width: 100%;">';
    for($i=1; $i<4; ++$i){


       echo '<div class="draftBorder">';
       echo $row['fullname'];
       echo '</div>';

       echo '<div class="draftBorder">';
       echo $row['fullname'];
       echo '</div>';

       echo '<div class="draftBorder">';
       echo $row['fullname'];
       echo '</div>';


    }

 echo '</div>';



    echo '<div style="display: block; width: 100%;">';
    for($i=1; $i<4; ++$i){
    $player = $row['player'.$i]

       echo '<div class="draftBorder">';
       echo $player;
       echo '</div>';

       echo '<div class="draftBorder">';
       echo $player;
       echo '</div>';

       echo '<div class="draftBorder">';
       echo $player;
       echo '</div>';


    }

 echo '</div>';

 }
?>
```

also change your `draftBorder` class to this

```
.draftBorder {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```